# Utilization of Matplotlib markers in axis ticks

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Is it possible to use Matplotlib markers in the axis ticks? For example, I want to achieve something, as shown below. I have three designs, and to identify them, I want to use the markers in the x-axis ticks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason to want to use matplotlib markers? Or is only the shape important?

You can use most unicode symbols:

```
pd.DataFrame({'value': [35,45,30]}, index=['★', '□', '◯']).plot.bar()
```

[image: unicode labels]

It also works for many (not all) LaTeX symbols:

```
pd.DataFrame({'value': [35,45,30]}, index=[r'$\star$', r'$\bigtriangleup$', r'$\bigcirc$']).plot.bar()
```

[image]

The advantage with the latter is that you can directly use LaTeX math symbols (actually any arbitrary text, including unicode symbols) as marker:

```
plt.plot([1,4,2,3,0], marker=r'$\bigtriangleup$', markersize=20)
plt.plot([0,1,4,2,3], marker='$\u26A1$', markersize=20)
```

[image: custom markers]

Comment: Thanks. The only reason to use markers as x-ticks is that I have many other plots where I have used markers as legends to differentiate designs. I wanted to keep all the plots consistent.